# Flexible CSS Column

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I'm looking for a solution where a bunch of same sized images in a list will be ordered in a flexible column like layout:

```
 _  _  _  __  __  __
|1||4||7||10||13||16|
 _  _  _  __  __  __
|2||5||8||11||14||17|
 _  _  _  __  __  __
|3||6||9||12||15||18|
```

The width of the container should be flexible so that it can expand horizontal. The solution needs only work in cutting edge browsers.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you want the images in a <ul> structure? Or do they float with divs?

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems that CSS [multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multi-column_layouts) does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

my gift to you...

```
.cols {
  margin:30px -1em -30px 0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:left;
  overflow:visible !important;
  zoom:1;
}
.cols + * {
    clear: both;
}
.cols:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
}
.cols:after {
  content:'';
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
.cols .break {
  width:100% !important;
  clear:both;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  display:none;
}
.cols > li {
  margin:0 0 30px 0;
  padding:0 1em 0 0;
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}
.cols > li > *:first-child { margin-top:0; }
.cols > li > *:last-child { margin-bottom:0; }
.cols > li > ul:last-child { margin-bottom:-30px; }
.cols.boxxes > li, .cols.image-strip li { margin:0 0 1em 0; }
.cols.boxxes > li:last-child, .cols.image-strip li:last-child { margin:0 0 30px 0; }
.cols.with2 > li { width:50%; }
.cols.with2 > li.take2 { width:100%; }
.cols.with3 > li { width:33.3333%; }
.cols.with3 > li.take2 { width:66.6666%; }
.cols.with3 > li.take3 { width:100%; }
.cols.with4 > li { width:25%; }
.cols.with4 > li.take2 { width:50%; }
.cols.with4 > li.take3 { width:75%; }
.cols.with4 > li.take4 { width:100%; }
.cols.with5 > li { width:20%; }
.cols.with5 > li.take2 { width:40%; }
.cols.with5 > li.take3 { width:60%; }
.cols.with5 > li.take4 { width:80%; }
.cols.with5 > li.take5 { width:100%; }
.cols.with6 > li { width:16.6666%; }
.cols.with6 > li.take2 { width:33.3333%; }
.cols.with6 > li.take3 { width:50%; }
.cols.with6 > li.take4 { width:66.6666%; }
.cols.with6 > li.take5 { width:83.3333%; }
.cols.with6 > li.take6 { width:100%; }
```

set up like this...

```
/* 5 cols */
<ul class="cols with5">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>

/* 3 cols 3/5, 1/5, 1/5*/
<ul class="cols with5">
    <li class="take3">...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

/* and so on */

you can do about 40 different liquid columns with that.